# Grid with max width and sticking image/text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to achieve a zig zag of images and text like following:

TEXT - IMAGE

IMAGE - TEXT

TEXT - IMAGE

and on mobile

Image

text

Image

text

Image text

--

First issue would be the different order on mobile than web, but I think I can achieve this with push and pull on the md classes.

My real issue is that on web version I need the text aligned on the left side but somehow always floating together.

When I put classes like
md-6 md-6 it automatically aligns the block to the left side and creates unneeded spacing. When I work with text align the text is not aligned anymore and when I use float the divs swap places. Is there an easy way to achieve something like this?

Since it needs to stay in the middle I plan on using a max-width.

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <h2>Snel van start</h2>
    <p>In minder dan 1 minuut je vacature op de smartphone van duizenden geschikte jobstudenten.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <%= image_tag("snel-van-start.png") %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <%= image_tag("alles-in-eigen-handen.png") %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <h2>Alles in eigen handen</h2>
    <p>Seal Jobs analyseert en sorteert alle kandidaten automatisch. Jij kiest dan de geschikte kandidaat, zonder tijd te verliezen.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <h2>Directe communicatie</h2>
    <p>Ideale kandidaat gevonden? Via de ingebouwde chatfunctie kan je met meteen verdere afspraken maken met je gematchte kandidaat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <%= image_tag("directe-communicatie.png") %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Gives something like this:

[image]

So how can I make sure there is no lost space between text and image?

Comment: @Swellar added.

Comment: do u have it somewhere working? where can we test it live? because I have

Comment: try sharing an working code on fiddler or snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like wrapping the inside content with a div and floating them so that your alignment will remain and the space issue will be resolved as.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
  <div class="pull-right">
     <h2>Snel van start</h2>
     <p>In minder dan 1 minuut je vacature op de smartphone van duizenden 
      geschikte jobstudenten.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
  <div class="pull-left">
     <%= image_tag("snel-van-start.png") %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```